# Why do we call LDAP objects as object classes

Tags: active-directory, ldap

I'm confused why we call objects in LDAP like 'inetorgperson' as ObjectClasses ?

Thanks.

Comment: Because it's a class of object, not an object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply put, in LDAP, object classes are the way to assign attributes to an LDAP entry. Object classes are really just descriptions of what you would expect an entry to "look like" or behave as.

An example (albeit a bit contrived) would be creating an LDAP entry of type 'Animal', perhaps called "cn=rover,ou=Pets,dc=example". As an Animal, it may have certain attributes, like an "age", or "genus", and "species". It also probably has a required "commonName" or "cn" attribute used for naming. If we added the 'Dog' object class to our pet, it may now include additional attributes, like "trick" or "breed" or "licenseNumber".

In your question, 'inetOrgPerson' (see [RFC2798](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2798.txt)) is an object class and a set of attributes associated with an individual who is part of an organization. By adding the 'inetOrgPerson' object class to an employee in a company, you may now define things like their "manager", or their "secretary", "employeeNumber", and others.

This is actually a pretty good link that describes more about LDAP Schemas, Object Classes, and Attributes: http://www.zytrax.com/books/ldap/ch3/

Answer (score 0):

I agree with jgnagy.

Also, objectClasses are unsubstantiated and LDAP entries are substantiated collections of objectClasses.

-jim

Comment: Please explain. The apparent meaning of these words is that objectClasses are unsubstantiated collections of objectClasses. Not sure what value is intended to be added by all this either.

Comment: objectClasses are objectClasses. They do not represent an entry within the DIT. Entries are a substantiation of objectClasses.

Comment: So you need a full stop after 'unsubstantiated'.